# Why the below statement in Java prints "2 + 2 = 22" instead of "2 + 2 = 4"

Tags: java, string

Why the below statement in Java prints `"2 + 2 = 22"`

```
System.out.println("2 + 2 = " + 2 + 2);
```

Comment: Evaluation happens from left to right. The numbers get casted to string.

Comment: Because it's understood as `String`, not `Number`.

Comment: Use some brackets, maybe? Calculation needs to be separate: `System.out.println("2 + 2 = " + (2 + 2));`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

because java '+' operator is first assigned on the left : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html

so

```
"2 + 2 = " + 2 + 2
```

is first evaluated to

```
 "2 + 2 = 2" + 2
```

and then

```
 "2 + 2 = 22"
```

Precedence rules can be overridden by explicit parentheses, you want

```
"2 + 2 = " + (2 + 2)
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to give the precedence order here. This way your brackets having the summation is executed first and then the concatenation. Otherwise it is evaluating from the left to right. Left most literal is a `String` and you concatenate your numbers to the `String` literal leading to the above result which is `"2 + 2 = 22"`.

```
System.out.println("2 + 2 = " + (2 + 2));
```

Answer (score 4):

If either of the arguments to `+` are a string, the return will be a string as well.

With that in mind, breaking this down you get:

`"2 + 2 = " + 2` => `"2 + 2 = 2"`

`"2 + 2 = 2" + 2` => `"2 + 2 = 22"`

If you want the math to happen before the String concatenation, you need to make sure it happens first, as @Ravindra's answer shows.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this:

> 15.18.1. String Concatenation Operator +
>
> If only one operand expression is of type String, then string
> conversion (§5.1.11) is performed on the other operand to produce a
> string at run time.

[JLS 15.18.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1)